# @PathVariable fileName results to 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a handler method like below that takes **`fileName`**

```
@GetMapping(value = ["/test/{fileName:.+}"], produces = [(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)])
fun getFile(@PathVariable fileName: String): ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(hashMapOf(Pair("fileName", fileName)))
}
```

I am getting some odd behaviour i.e

- Calling `/test/item-1.exx` results to `{"fileName": "item-1.exx"}`
- Calling `/test/item-1.855` results to `{"fileName": "item-1.855"}`
- Calling `/test/item-1.pn8` results to `{"fileName": "item-1.pn8"}`

But if I try to to call the method with valid extension I get **`406 Not Acceptable`**.

- Calling `/test/item-1.png` results to **`406 Not Acceptable`**
- Calling `/test/item-1.jpg` results to **`406 Not Acceptable`**
- Calling `/test/item-1.exe` results to **`406 Not Acceptable`**

I get following exception

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

How to solve this problem? I want to be able to call the method using valid extension.

Comment: Using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of content negotiation, just try to add `Content-Type` to request header, it should fix this problem, or disable content negotiation. check out this link: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [@Jaiwo99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48896204/5065092) gave me hint on what needs to be done. Here's a solutions that I found.

Solution 1: Configure ContentNegotiation

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer
                .useJaf(false)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    };
}
```

Solution 2: Edit application.yml / application.properties

```
spring:
    mvc:
        media-types:
            png: application/json
            jpg: application/json
            jpeg: application/json
```